# Dotfuscator - Failed to resolve System.Reflection.BindingFlags

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotfuscator

I updated Visual Studio last week end. And now DotFuscator Community is failing `Failed to resolve System.Reflection.BindingFlags`. My project is dotnet core 3.0.

```
  [Build Output] Analyzing Markup...
  [Build Output]
  [Build Output] Renaming...
  [Build Output]
  [Build Output] Updating Markup...
  [Build Output]
  [Build Output] Writing map file to C:\code\quant\Dotfuscated\Map_win.xml
  [Build Output]
  [Smart Obfuscation] User Type QuantWS.Startup was excluded from renaming by AspNetStartupRule for the following reasons: Type is an ASP.NET Core Startup Type.
  [Build Output] Writing Assemblies...
  [Build Output]
  [Build Output] Running C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ilasm.exe /OUTPUT=C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\~QuantWS.0\stub-pdb\QuantWS.dll /nologo /PE64 /X64  /quiet /dll  /PDB /resource=C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\~QuantWS.0\QuantWS.dll.res /MDV=v4.0.30319 /MSV=2.0 C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\~QuantWS.0\QuantWS.dll.il
  [Build Output]
  [Build Output] Running C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ilasm.exe /OUTPUT=C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\~Iwala.d.3\stub-pdb\Iwala.dll /nologo  /quiet /dll  /PDB /resource=C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\~Iwala.d.3\Iwala.dll.res /MDV=v4.0.30319 /MSV=2.0 C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\~Iwala.d.3\Iwala.dll.il
  [Build Output]

  ╬┤╛?┤a└φ╡─╥∞│ú:  ag7: Failed to resolve System.Reflection.BindingFlags
     ╘┌ adw.a(aiv A_0)
     ╘┌ afl.a(aiv A_0, Object A_1)
     ╘┌ afl.a(agc A_0, aiv A_1)
     ╘┌ afl.a(UInt16 A_0, ahz A_1, aek A_2)
     ╘┌ afl.c(ahd A_0)
     ╘┌ afl.d(ahd A_0)
     ╘┌ afl.c(aip A_0)
     ╘┌ afl.h(aip A_0)
     ╘┌ afl.b()
     ╘┌ afl.d()
     ╘┌ afl.k()
     ╘┌ afl.l()
     ╘┌ aea.<>c.<BuildMetadata>b__2_0(afl builder, ad8 _)
     ╘┌ ahq.a[a,b](a A_0, Func`3 A_1)
     ╘┌ aea.a(ahq A_0, afl A_1)
     ╘┌ aea.a(ahq A_0, adp A_1, ahp A_2)
     ╘┌ aea.b(ahq A_0, adp A_1, ahp A_2)
     ╘┌ ahq.a(String A_0, ahp A_1)
     ╘┌ t4.a(Boolean A_0, String A_1, f7 A_2, j9 A_3, String A_4)
     ╘┌ t4.a(String A_0, String A_1, f7 A_2)
     ╘┌ t3.a(f7 A_0, String A_1, String A_2)
     ╘┌ lk.a(ISession A_0, f7 A_1, List`1 A_2, String A_3, String A_4, Boolean A_5)
     ╘┌ lj.a(ISession A_0, f7 A_1, List`1 A_2, String A_3, String A_4, Boolean A_5)
     ╘┌ lu.a(ISession A_0, f7 A_1, d1 A_2, String A_3)
     ╘┌ lu.v(ISession A_0)
     ╘┌ lq.a(Dictionary`2 A_0)
     ╘┌ lq.a(IOptions A_0, qz A_1, Dictionary`2 A_2, h9 A_3)
     ╘┌ lq.<>c__DisplayClass22_1.<Run>b__0()
     ╘┌ lq.b(Action A_0)
     ╘┌ lq.c()
     ╘┌ aal.a(lu A_0, ISession A_1, Dictionary`2 A_2, rr A_3, qf A_4)
     ╘┌ aal.a(IOptions A_0, lu A_1, ISession A_2, Dictionary`2 A_3)
     ╘┌ aai.a(String[] A_0)
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio did you previously use, and what version are you currently using? What version of Dotfuscator Community (CE) are you using?

Comment: @JoeSewell Currently Visual Studio Community 2019 16.3.4. Previous one is also 2019 16.3.x. Dotfuscator Community 5.42.0.9514.

Comment: I work for the Dotfuscator team. This looks like an issue with Dotfuscator writing updated debugging symbols. Two things to try: (1) update to [the latest version of Dotfuscator Community](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/downloads), 5.44.0, which was released yesterday and fixes a related issue, or (2) [disable "Emit Debugging Symbols"](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/gui_settings.html#pctoc-build-configuration).

Comment: @JoeSewell Version 5.44.0.10087 still not working. Same error. By the way, is such kind of warnings related:
"EXEC : [Build Output] warning : MoveNext overrides MoveNext which could not be found. [C:\code\quant\QuanTradeV2\QuanTradeV2.csproj]
EXEC : [Build Output] warning : SetStateMachine overrides SetStateMachine which could not be found. [C:\code\quant\QuanTradeV2\QuanTradeV2.csproj]
"

Comment: @JoeSewell Visual Studio Community 2019 is updated again. Now version is 16.3.5. The error is not changed.

Comment: Did you try my second suggestion to disable the debugging symbol generation?

Comment: @JoeSewell Not yet. If this makes error logs missing line numbers, it would not be acceptable.

Comment: @JoeSewell With /debug:off switch the command succeeds.

Comment: We think this might be a bug, but we can't reproduce it with the information you've given so far. I've handed this case over to our support staff; please [contact them](https://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support/) with the details of your issue so we can reproduce and investigate the problem.

Comment: Hi it's me again. Seems this problem is still not fixed?

Comment: We weren't able to get a reproduction of the issue last time we spoke. Our support team says you contacted them this morning, so please communicate with them so we can reproduce the issue and fix it.